# Discriminating A Union of Classes

Tags: typescript, union, discriminated-union

Using Typescript 3.4 I am attempting to discriminate between a union of typescript classes based on a single readonly field (discriminator) locate on each subclass; in itself seems simple enough but I cannot seem to get it to resolve.

Below is a link to a playground, where the createFruit method should be able to take a generic parameter to filter the next property by the discriminator. Any insights would be greatly appreciated; however, it seems to allows evaluates to never.

```
abstract class Fruit {
    abstract readonly fruitType: string;
}

class Banana extends Fruit {
    fruitType = 'banana';
    length = 2;
    color = 'yellow';
}

class Pear extends Fruit {
    fruitType = 'pear';
    roundness = 'very round';
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    fruitType = 'apple';
    fallOfMan = true;
    hasWorms = true;
}

type KnownFruits = Banana | Pear | Apple;

type FruitTypes = KnownFruits['fruitType'];

type FruitDiscriminator<T extends FruitTypes> = Extract<KnownFruits, { fruitType: T }>;

let createFruit = <T extends FruitTypes>(fruitType: T, props: FruitDiscriminator<T>) => { }

createFruit('pear', {} ) // Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Fruit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20readonly%20fruitType%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Banana%20extends%20Fruit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fruitType%20%3D%20'banana'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20length%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%20%3D%20'yellow'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Pear%20extends%20Fruit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fruitType%20%3D%20'pear'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20roundness%20%3D%20'very%20round'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Apple%20extends%20Fruit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fruitType%20%3D%20'apple'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fallOfMan%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hasWorms%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20KnownFruits%20%3D%20Banana%20%7C%20Pear%20%7C%20Apple%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FruitTypes%20%3D%20KnownFruits%5B'fruitType'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FruitDiscriminator%3CT%20extends%20FruitTypes%3E%20%3D%20Extract%3CKnownFruits%2C%20%7B%20fruitType%3A%20T%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20createFruit%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20FruitTypes%3E(fruitType%3A%20T%2C%20props%3A%20FruitDiscriminator%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AcreateFruit('pear'%2C%20%7B%7D%20))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `fruitType` in the derived classes is of type `string` not the string literal type associated with the string literal. Typescript will by default widen literal types to the base type when initializing fields. To get around this you can use an `as const` assertion, or make thew field `readonly` (or specify the string literal type manually but that is going to duplicate the string)

The `readonly` solution makes the most sense as the type should not change :

```
abstract class Fruit {
    abstract readonly fruitType: string;
}

class Banana extends Fruit {
    readonly fruitType = 'banana';
    length = 2;
    color = 'yellow';
}

class Pear extends Fruit {
    readonly fruitType = 'pear';
    roundness = 'very round';
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    readonly fruitType = 'apple';
    fallOfMan = true;
    hasWorms = true;
}

type KnownFruits = Banana | Pear | Apple;

type FruitTypes = KnownFruits['fruitType'];

type FruitDiscriminator<T extends FruitTypes> = Extract<KnownFruits, { fruitType: T }>;

let createFruit = <T extends FruitTypes>(fruitType: T, props: FruitDiscriminator<T>) => { }

// ok
createFruit('pear', {
    fruitType: 'pear',
    roundness: ""
})
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that explanation!